# How to UnTar a .tar.gz MultipartFile send in a request and add the files to a List<File>

Tags: java, spring, rest, file, multipartfile

I want to extract all the files in my .tar.gz MultipartFile and add the files to a List

```
@RequestMapping(value="/importFile", produces="application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ca.alea.cam.api.model.Response importFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) throws ContentRepositoryDaoException, Exception {
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
        
        InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
        GzipCompressorInputStream gzipIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(in);
        TarArchiveInputStream tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzipIn);
        TarArchiveEntry entry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
        
        while (entry != null) {
            // untar and add each file in MultipartFile to fileList
            // fileList.add()...
            //fileList.add(entry.getFile()) -> This returns a null, as expected from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveEntry.html#getFile--
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `entry.getName()` instead of getFile.

Comment: Hi, thanks but doesnt `.getName()` return a String? How would I save that as a File and add it to `fileList`? Thanks

Comment: You know that callers of your REST API who are running on other computers will not be able to read those files, right?  A `File` object is just a file path;  it does not contain the file contents.